# AWK don't use first value of a column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

First of all, thank you for your help. I have a problem with awk and using the while read. I have a file separated in two columns that each column has 8 values. My script consist of selecting the second columnn and download 8 different files and decompress them. The problem is that the my script doesn't download the first value of the column.

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | while read line
do  
     echo "Downloading fasta files from NCBI..."
     awk '{print $2}' | wget -i- 2>> log 
     gzip -d *.gz
done
```

This is the file I am using

```
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhi    https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/003/717/755/GCF_003717755.1_ASM371775v1/GCF_003717755.1_ASM371775v1_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Paratyphi_A  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/818/115/GCF_000818115.1_ASM81811v1/GCF_000818115.1_ASM81811v1_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Paratyphi_B  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/018/705/GCF_000018705.1_ASM1870v1/GCF_000018705.1_ASM1870v1_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/011/182/555/GCA_011182555.2_ASM1118255v2/GCA_011182555.2_ASM1118255v2_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/006/945/GCF_000006945.2_ASM694v2/GCF_000006945.2_ASM694v2_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_diarizonae    https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/003/324/755/GCF_003324755.1_ASM332475v1/GCF_003324755.1_ASM332475v1_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_arizonae  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/635/675/GCA_900635675.1_31885_G02/GCA_900635675.1_31885_G02_translated_cds.faa.gz
Salmonella_bongori  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/006/113/225/GCF_006113225.1_ASM611322v2/GCF_006113225.1_ASM611322v2_translated_cds.faa.gz
```

Comment: `while read -r line; do url=${line##* }; wget -i "$url" 2>>logg; done < filename`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but it doesn't work because it takes all the line and I want only the url

Comment: `url=${line##* }` uses the parameter expansion with substring removal to trim from the beginning up thought the last space leaving only the `url` from `line`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the download. Check the output of

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$1" | while read line
do  
     awk '{print $2}'
done
```

This also prints only 7 of the 8 urls.  When entering the loop, the `read` reads the first line into the variable `line`. However, you never use that variable, so the line is lost. Then `awk` reads the remaining 7 lines from stdin in one go. The loop only runs once.

You probably wanted to write

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$1" | while read -r line
do
     echo "Downloading fasta files from NCBI..."
     echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}' | wget -i- 2>> log 
     gzip -d *.gz
done
```

But there is an easier and safer way:

```
awk '{print $2}' "$1" | wget -i- 2>> log 
gzip -d *.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the command `cut` is made to select a column, why not simply issue:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for url in $(cut -f2 "$1")
do 
  wget "$url" >> log
done
gzip -d *.gz
```